# How to re-purpose Google Search Appliance T4 model?

Tags: google-search-appliance

I want to re-purpose my Google Search Appliance T4 model (G-100) and install a linux server. I searched online but I didn't find any good solution.

Comment: The GSA already runs on CentOS, a linux distribution.

Comment: T4 appliances cannot be repurposed, to my knowledge.

Comment: I think this would be a better question on a different StackExchange site.  ServerFault, perhaps?

Comment: @TerryChambers-Onix Google says that we cannot repurpose a T4 GSA, but I checked online there are few ways to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I unlocked my T4 by clearing the RAID Config, making sure it was initialised. Then booting from a liveUSB (F11 after the RAID config) I used centos7 live and dhcp, then updating the iDRAC and bios from the Dell website, iDRAC had to be updated first. Then remove the jumpers, reboot and done. Took me a couple of hours of fiddling and rebooting to get it but now have a T4 with all the bells and whistles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in to a point on a T4.  How do we get into the setup though, it is password protected.  To this point, I have gotten past the password to get to the BIOS by removing the PWRD_EN Jumper. If I can flash the BIOS, should be able to reload to a Windows based system or even another Linux system if necessary.